# Removing rows with duplicated column values based on another column's value

Tags: sql

[image]

Hey guys, maybe this is a basic SQL qn. Say I have this very simple table, I need to run a simple sql statement to return a result like this:

[image]

Basically, the its to dedup Name based on it's row's Value column, whichever is larger should stay.

Thanks!

Comment: Basically you have to define your primary key.

Comment: Why does every row have the same ID? Is it possible to have a different value? Is it possible to have the same name with different IDs? Or maybe is ID column always "1" and we could remove it from the example?

Comment: Do you need it only once or every time you want to insert something?

Comment: I'm trying to query from an enterprise table, so I dont own the table and have the power to change primary key here. This is just a subset of the real table, there are IDs 2,3,4 with the same pattern of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Framing the problem correctly would help you figure it out.

"Deduplication" suggests altering the table - starting with a state with duplicates, ending with a state without them. Usually done in three steps (getting the rows without duplicates into temp table, removing original table, renaming temp table).

"Removing rows with duplicated column values" also suggests alteration of data and derails train of thought.

What you do want is to get the entire table, and in cases where the columns you care about have multiple values attached get the highest one. One could say... **group by** columns you care about? And attach them to the highest value, a **maximum** value?

```
select id,name,max(value) from table group by id,name
```

Comment: This works! https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vbh3NMzziYb4KSvLfEy2c8/1

Comment: How would you write this so that max(value) is returned as the second column? I couldn't make the syntax work. 

E.g. 
select id, (max(value) from table group by id,name),  name
select id, (max(value) as value from table group by id,name),  name

Comment: @kaanchan you mean `select id,max(value),name from table group by id,name`? column order does not matter to sql, you can just swap them

Comment: @Deltharis Thanks. Reading your comment, I realized I didn't understand group by and read up on it.